# Why am I getting jquery .load() status as blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Please check the javascript part of the code. When I click on the link, I want it to load a specific page into "content" div while showing "loading" div while the page is being fetched. I also want to make some other changes when the requested page has been loaded into the "content" div. How do I determine that the load has been successful? The "status" is always blank.

Edit: This is not a duplicate as suggested. My question doesn't ask about custom parameters.

```js
function ajaxload(status) 
{
 alert(status);
    if (status === "success") 
    {
        $("div#loading").hide();
        $("div#content").show();
     $("input#keysearch").blur();
    } 
    else 
    {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error";
        $("div#loading").text(msg);
    }
}

$("div#keylist ul li").on("click", function(event) 
{
        event.preventDefault();
        $("div#content").hide();
        $("div#loading").show();
        $("div#content").load("http://stacksnippets.net/js",ajaxload(status));
}
);
```

```css
#loading {
 display:none;
 border: 1px solid #F00;
 bottom:0;
 left:15vw;
 width:70vw;
 height:80vh;
    overflow-y:auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 padding:2vh 2vw;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align:center;
position: fixed;
}

#content {
 visibility:visible;
 border: 1px solid #F00;
 position:fixed;
 left:15vw;
 right:15vw;
 bottom:0;
 width:70vw;
 height:80vh;
    overflow-y:auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    text-align:justify;
    z-index:0;
 padding:2vh 2vw;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="keylist">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="">ABORT</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ABS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ACCESS</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>

<div id="loading">
  Loading...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery function **[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** return status in second argument, Try to do it like following :

```
$( "div#content" ).load( "http://stacksnippets.net/js", function( response, status, xhr ) {
    ajaxload(status);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Second code will not work since you executing `ajaxload` before `.load` and pass undfined to `.load`.